# Did Visser Three think the whales attacking him were Andalites?

Tags: animorphs, andalites

Near the end of [#4 The Message](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Message_(novel)), when Visser is in his Mardrut morph, racing after the Animorphs, he is attacked by whales (real ones) just as he was about to catch up. They attack him in a highly coordinated and aggressive way, forcing him to retreat. It must have been embarrassing for him.

Now, If I was the Visser, I would have immediately assumed that the whales were actually "Andalite bandits", and that the Andalites' numbers were larger than the Yeerks had earlier estimated.

Or maybe the Visser didn't know anything about whales, and thought they were simply defending their territory? He might not have wanted to ask his human controllers, as he probably didn't want to mention the affair to anyone, given the embarrassment of being defeated by whales.

Did the Visser increase his estimate of the number of "Andalite bandits" after being attacked by the whales?

Comment: I don't have the faintest idea what you're talking about, but if you think it contains spoilers, why don't you put the spoilery bits behind spoiler tags >!

Comment: @MrLister The main spoiler is the fact that whales come and save the Animorphs during the climax at the end of the book. That is the whole premise of the quesiton, so 90% of the text would have to be hidden behind a spoiler tag. I've done that previously, and the majority of commenters seemed to think it was a bad idea.

Comment: I don't have text to back this up, but I'm pretty sure they say near the end of the books that the Yeerks originally had no idea how many "Andalites" they were up against.

Comment: @Axelrod I see. I gotta stop asking these questions until I've read all the books. I get too many spoilers for myself :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't receive any insight into the Visser's thought process for this particular fight, but it's a safe assumption that he assumed they were Andalites.  After all, Humpback Whales are not particularly aggressive, which research would have revealed very quickly afterwards, and since the 'bandits' themselves utilized the whale morph just a few books later, it would be obvious (if wrong) in retrospect.